# PDT installed but PHP Perspective is missing

Tags: php, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-pdt

I have installed PDT 2.1 but i can't switch to the PHP Perspective, any ideas?

Comment: How did you install it? All-in-one bundle or update site?

Comment: you mention that you solved the problem, could you please explain how??

Comment: cite: "I have solved the problem with installation of Eclipse PHP IDE."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem with installation of Eclipse PHP IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Errr... just guessing: Have you tried to click on the button with a litte "plus"-sign on it left hand to the perspective buttons? There should be an "Other" section containing all available perspectives.

Second guess:
I've had the same issue some time ago. First: Do you use the most recent Ganymede release of Eclipse? I tried to install PDT by hand and the perspective was missing to. After i installed PDT trough the "Install new Software" Feature (PDT is now part of the standard repository) it worked perfectly.

Comment: yes, I'm using Eclipse 3.4.2. But i have installed PDT over Eclipse and not manually....

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, which version of the JVM/JRE (Java Runtime) are you using ? Is it not an old one ?

Does it work better if you install a recent version of the JRE from [sun's website](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/?intcmp=1281) ?

I am not sure which version is required by PDT, but using latest JVM could maybe help ?

Comment: $ java -version
java version "1.6.0_10"

I have solved the problem with installation of Eclipse PHP IDE :)

Comment: Hu, too bad it wasn't just a problem of JRE version :-(

Answer (score 0):

PDT 2.1 only supports Eclipse 3.5. It is strange that you didn't see any warning while installing it. If you wish to continue using Eclipse 3.4.x, install PDT 2.0.1

Comment: The Eclipse PHP IDE was v 3.5 :)